Kicad and Flatcam - how to route internal cutout areas
I use Kicad for PCB design these days, and usually get the boards made professionally. However, sometimes I want something quickly, and if it's very simple or I just want a space model I sometimes route the boards on a 3020 CNC using FlatCAM (8.993 beta) to create the tool paths for tracks, outline and drill holes. Works well.
However I currently have a small simple board that has an internal cutout area (not just a circle that could be drilled). Whilst I can get FlatCAM to generate the tool path for the external board outline OK, I can see no way of getting it to route the internal cutout.
The only way round this I have found is to use one of the user (non-conductive) layers, and create the outline shape with any necessary cutouts on that, then in FlatCAM create an isolation routing tool path from that rather than a cutout from the edge cuts layer. But, I can't help feeling this is just not the right way, and it should be doable from the edge cuts layer.
Is there a way?

I just finished a PCB with that feature- I exported the mechanical layer as SVG and flatcam generated a tool path that used both onlines - however the cutout tool path was on the wrong side of the line. Maybe there is some way of changing that.

If you didn't find the solution yet, here is a nice answer:
https://altrish.co.uk/2023/05/24/editing-irregular-pcb-shapes-in-flatcam/
...and many more tricks on flatcam

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Can you summarize the answer so if the link goes down there is still an answer

Thanks for your comment. In the end I had done it by creating (using KiCAD) the inner and outer profile on a spare user layer and gerber file, then creating another isolation routing CNC job for that alone, using a 1.5mm end mill, multiple passes of 0.5mm deep per pass. Not sure that is how it is intended to be done, but it did work.

You can edit the geometriy generated by flatcam and add additional paths where you want to cut. When you generate the CNCObject you'll see the cuts on the added paths. The link above contains also a small video sowing this process.
